# Application crashes every time I click the on product that I bought before

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Does anyone have a similar problem or is in the similar situation that can help me?

I published an app that has IAP base64 public key not correctly configured,  then went to purchase few IAP with my phone(nexus 5) and this is how I know it wasn't correctly configured because of the error message it showed, however, the payment went through. But I never got the in-game item that I purchased. I then proceed to update the game and set the base64public key correctly, then went to update the game on my phone, however now every time I go to the store and click to buy the item that was already purchased before, the game will just crash. I tried this with other phone and it didn't crash.

TL;DR: buy an IAP "item a" -> game crashed -> put the correct base64publickey from android dev acc -> update the game on the phone -> now it crashes every time I go to IAP and click "item a" (Nexus 5)

Here is some of the crash report that I submitted from nexus 5:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
 at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:108)
 at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:125)
 at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:967)
 at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges.alert(FlowBridges.java:619)
 at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges.complain(FlowBridges.java:611)
 at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges$3.onIabPurchaseFinished(FlowBridges.java:518)
 at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:392)
 at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:338)
 at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges.buyFeature(FlowBridges.java:714)
 at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeTouchesEnd(Native Method)
 at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.handleActionUp(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:129)
 at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView$9.run(Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java:257)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

and another one is the same except these 3 lines:

```
at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges.alert(FlowBridges.java:610)
at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges.complain(FlowBridges.java:602)
at com.theblackwhisker.animatcher.FlowBridges.buyFeature(FlowBridges.java:701)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think you are using any alert or ui element from background thread may be in doInBackground() of async task.

Comment: post your code here. Exception shows you are using some UI element in background Thread.

Comment: It doesn't happen with any other phone, but that's mainly I didn't use any other phone to buy the IAP on the first version, so the updated version work fine. I suspect my nexus 5 might have store some data over/cache of the old version even after the update, however it still crashes even after completely clear the cache/data for this app.